# How to programm a Lattice board?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, lattice

I wrote a few lines in VHDL and I declared pins into a lpf file for my Lattice MarchX03 board. But now I want to flash the board and honestly the documentation is very unclear.

So I got Diamond Software which from what I understand is juste a IDE that let you programm/compile VHDL.

The VHDL simulator that came with that is Active-HDL software?

Finaly, the bitstream generator is a software called Synplify Pro?

So if I get it right, I need to synthetize my VHDL design with Synplify Pro than use Diamond software to programm the Board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working around, I finaly find out how. Synplify Pro is the synthetize but you don't need to open it. In Diamond, you see this panel when you are in the workspace:
[image]

Click on the second tab "Process", in my case it was hidden from my screen resolution

The following window will open and as you can see there is the ouput file generator. In my case, the bitstream wasn't generate because of Map design problem,but there you go guys. Also you can either use JEDEC or bitstream file as input for the programmer.

[image]